# How to load $scope.$on last?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing, angularjs-routing

How can I delay value that I get from `$scope.$emit` and display it after the page is loaded? I have this function:

```
   $scope.ActiveMenu = function (number)
    {
        $scope.selectedLink = number;

        $scope.$emit('onAccountMenuSelection', $scope.selectedLink);

    }
```

On other controller I have :

```
$rootScope.$on('onAccountMenuSelection', _onAccountMenuSelection);
```

now I send value from one page to another but it always executes first...so how can I set that that value is execute last?

Answer (score 1):

Do `$emit` on `$timeout`, that will run the code on the next digest cycle.

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.$emit('onAccountMenuSelection', $scope.selectedLink);
})
```

Comment: @None do you want to send data with the emit? could you update your question please..

Comment: i have menu on layout and it have one controller, then i have content and it have another controller,thats why i use emit....but problem is that in content i have $scope.selectedLink = 0; and when i emit data from first page...for example number 5 it displays me number 5 and then 0 and i want that displays me 0 and then 5

Comment: because somehow things that i emit displays first and i dont want that

Comment: @None why you don't use `ngRoute` if you want to pass some parameter on view..you could just pass it from route

Comment: im using ui.router...im not that good with angular to know how to handle with that thats why im using $emit :)

Comment: is it possible to do that with $emit because im already start with it ?

Comment: don't go for $emit then..take use of `ui-router` create a new state, could I know how you redirecting from one page to another?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81985/discussion-between-none-and-pankajparkar).

Comment: i lost my connection yesterday...can we continue now somehow in chat?

Comment: @None I can't now..sorry

Comment: @None after a 9 hours..I'll available for chat.. Thanks..till then you can try to create plunkr of it..